# Load combobox with range of another sheet

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2010, vba

I have one combobox in one sheet named `extraçao` with a combobox,

[image]

and I have written this code:

```
  Sub Validar_Idades()

  Dim aba1 As Worksheet
  Set aba1 = Sheets("IDADE")

  Dim aba2 As Worksheet
  Set aba2 = Sheets("EXTRAÇÃO")

  aba2.ComboBox1.Clear
  aba2.ComboBox1.List = aba1.range("A2:A" & aba1.range("A" &         aba1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

End Sub
```

Why don't I see `combobox1`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an important distinction between Worksheet objects and Sheet objects:

- Worksheet can contain only data (in cells)
- Sheet can contain data, and other objects like Charts, combo boxes, list boxes, etc
- To declare a Worksheet variable use Worksheet type
- To declare a Sheet variable use its CodeName, that appears before the name in brackets:

[image]

.

Try one of the 2 options bellow

```
Option Explicit

Sub Validar_Idades()

    Dim aba1 As Worksheet           'Worksheet contain only data (no objects)
    Set aba1 = Worksheets("IDADE")

    'To declare a variable of type Sheet you need to use its "CodeName"

    Dim aba2 As Sheet2              'Sheet can contain data and other objects
    Set aba2 = Sheets("EXTRAÇÃO")   'like ListBoxes, Charts, ComboBoxes, etc

    aba2.ComboBox1.Clear
    aba2.ComboBox1.List = aba1.Range("A2:A" & _
                                aba1.Range("A" & aba1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Validar_Idades2()

    'or simply use its code name instead of a variable

    Sheet2.ComboBox1.Clear
    Sheet2.ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & _
                                Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet` class does not have a `combobox1` property - since of course not every worksheet has that control on it - which is why the compiler objects to your code. In addition to using the codename, as Paul Bica suggested, (though there is no generic Sheet object - each sheet is effectively its own class), you could simply declare your variable as `Object` rather than `Worksheet` so the code is late bound and the compiler won't object. Alternatively, you can access the control through the `OLEObjects` property of the `Worksheet` class:

```
aba2.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.List = aba1.Range("A2:A" & _
                                aba1.Range("A" & aba1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

Comment: Random comment from over a year after your comment but using your method gives a Permission denied error.  Any idea why?  Objects are not locked or protected.

Comment: Most likely your control has a `ListFillRange` set.